# ckeditor | the "required" attribute within <textarea> tag is not working

Tags: validation, ckeditor, textarea, required

When using `CKEDITOR` with `<textarea>` tag, it's not working.

```
 <textarea id="editor1" name="description" class="form-control" cols="10" rows="10" required></textarea>

 <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
 </script>
```

Any sugesstions?

Answer (score 6):

Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-required

You need to assign an event handler to CKEditor which "replaces" native `textarea` element.

---

If you are looking for more fancy way of showing messages than standard alert dialogs, please try using [notifications](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_notifications.html). Below is the most basic example (when you press `submit` button while having empty editor, notification will be displayed):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    language: 'en',
    extraPlugins: 'notification'
});

editor.on( 'required', function( evt ) {
    editor.showNotification( 'This field is required.', 'warning' );
    evt.cancel();
} );
```

Please note that contrary to what is written in documentation the `notification` plugin seems to be included into every preset. You can check it by using search box of `Available Plugins`, list box in [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder).

Comment: Can i get the native HTML validation (tooltip one), as this would be confusing (tooltip and alert within same form).

Comment: I don't think you will show two messages because when CKEditor replaces the `textarea` it in fact set it to `display:none` so no tooltip validation will be fired here. If however you don't want to use alerts, you can try using notifications. Let  me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<script>
function validate() {
    var resultado_validacion=true;
    $("#editor_error").html("");
    var editor_val = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText().trim();
    if(!(editor_val.length>0)){
        $("#editor_error").html("Se requiere contenido del oficio");
        resultado_validacion=false;
    }       

    return resultado_validacion;
}

</script>    
<form  onSubmit="return validate();">
```